# Dns 301 to one address and A record to another

Tags: dns, domain, redirection

So I got domain.com.
I want to make An A record pointing at 12.34.56.78
But I also want http://domain.com to redirect to http:myotherdomain.com (301)

Is this possible?
12.34.56.78 is not begin used for web at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You will need to install a web server on 12.34.56.78 that responds to requests for http://domain.com with the 301 redirect to http://myotherdomain.com/.

Answer (score 0):

What Michael is implying is that you have to install the web server at 12.34.56.78 to do the redirect.  It can't be accomplished via DNS if the A record for domain.com actually exists.

Much depends on what the A record is for (i.e., what you're running at 12.34.56.78).  It is possible to set up a CNAME record to redirect domain.com to myotherdomain.com but it requires that the A record doesn't exist.  It is possible to set domain.com up so that a web server and a mail server operate at different IPs.  It would rely on something like:

domain.com IN CNAME myotherdomain.com
www.domain.com IN CNAME myotherdomain.com
domain.com IN MX 10 mymailserver.domain.com
mymailserver.domain.com IN A 12.34.56.79

and in the other zone file

myotherdomain.com IN A 12.34.56.80

You would then set up the myotherdomain.com web server to also answer queries for domain.com. Confusing enough?

Comment: You can't have a CNAME and an MX record for the same hostname in DNS. The presence of a CNAME for a hostname means that you may not have any other records for that hostname of any type.

Comment: mydomain.com is for a game server and www.mydomain.com is for website.

Comment: Michael, while it may be considered bad form to use them at the same time, it is possible (and usable).  It depends on the DNS server (another example: many DNS servers consider the underscore to be an illegal character but the MS DNS server allows it).  All that said, I agree that the better solution is to set up the redirect in the web protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I had this scenario myself several times and solved it by creating a small site that responds to "domain.com" and 301 redirects to "myotherdomain.com".

To help other solve the same scenario, I have created a small free service at [www.301redirect.it](https://www.301redirect.it) that can do it for you. I hope it's helpful.

Comment: It might be helpful to add the *process* of using the service, rather than just mention the *product*, as per how we suggest people recommend software.